# Record Id lost after authentication with third party. How to keep it?

Tags: apex, visualforce, httprequest

I have a button on a Lead. When clicked it sends a POST request to a third party non-salesforce. In order to to do the POST request I need authorization from the third party. Getting authorization means logging in to the third party with a pop up window, then getting redirected to my org.

The few redirects make me loose the Lead Id I was working with.

Controller

```
public class Infusionsoft {

public static String response {get; set;}
public static String accessToken {get; set;}
public static String accessCode {get; set;}
public Id currentLeadId {get;set;}

public Infusionsoft(ApexPages.StandardController con) {
  currentLeadId = con.getId();

  system.debug('Lead Id=' + currentLeadId);

}


//Get authorization code
public PageReference firstRedirect() {
    if( ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code') != null) {
        accessCode = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code');
        return secondRedirect();
    }
    else {
        return new PageReference('https://signin.infusionsoft.com/app/oauth/authorize?client_id=*****************&redirect_uri=https://touchpointcrm--dev--c.cs19.visual.force.com/apex/InfusionsoftAuthorization&response_type=code&scope=full');
    }
}
//Get access token & refresh token
public PageReference secondRedirect() {
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 

    req.setEndpoint('https://api.infusionsoft.com/token'); 

    string bodyRequest = ''; 
    string bodyResponse = ''; 

    bodyRequest += 'client_id=*********************';
    bodyRequest += '&client_secret=**********';
    bodyRequest += '&code=' + accessCode;
    bodyRequest += '&grant_type=authorization_code';
    bodyRequest += '&redirect_uri=https://touchpointcrm--dev--c.cs19.visual.force.com/apex/InfusionsoftAuthorization';



    req.setBody(bodyRequest); 
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
    req.setHeader('Content-length', string.ValueOf(bodyRequest.length())); 

    req.setMethod('POST'); 
    req.setTimeout(10000); 


    HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 


    //Parse returned JSON
    JSONParser  parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
     if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME)){
      String fieldName = parser.getText();
      parser.nextToken();
      String fieldValue=parser.getText();
      if(fieldName == 'access_token') {

        accessToken= parser.getText();
        break;
       }
      }
     }

    system.debug('Access Token=' + accessToken);

    //query lead using Id

    //send another POST request with lead info using accessToken.


    return null;
}
}
```

VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="Infusionsoft" standardStylesheets="false" action="{!firstRedirect}">
    <h2>
        Lead id is {!currentLeadId}
    </h2>
</apex:page>
```

Test Class

```
@isTest(seealldata=true)
private class InfusionsoftTest {

    static void sendLeadCallout() {


        String token = 'sdafklj3kj22wfdfsa';

        Lead testLead = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Title, Company, Street, City, State, PostalCode, Country, Phone, MobilePhone, Email, LeadSource
                  FROM Lead LIMIT 1];

        Infusionsoft cont = new Infusionsoft(new ApexPages.StandardController(testLead));

        Test.setCurrentPageReference(new PageReference('Page.InfusionsoftAuthorization'));

        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('code', 'asdfjhkjhwlajksdhf3w');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('state', testLead.Id);
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new InfusionsoftMock());

        cont.firstRedirect();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the state parameter in your initial OAuth call, and it should be given back to you when you're returned to your page. The state can be set here:

```
  return new PageReference(
      'https://signin.infusionsoft.com/app/oauth/authorize?'+
      'client_id=*****************&'+
      'redirect_uri=https://touchpointcrm--dev--c.cs19.visual.force.com/apex/InfusionsoftAuthorization&'+
      'response_type=code&scope=full&state='+currentLeadId);
```

You'll be given this parameter back upon return so that you can re-populate your page's state.

Comment: so on the second redirect I can access the value in state?

Comment: @TylerZika Yes, it should appear in your page's parameter (e.g. `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('state')`)

Comment: How would I test for the state of the url? Like this?System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('state', testLead.Id);

Comment: @TylerZika Yes, for your unit test, you can manipulate the parameters directly.

Comment: Could you check out my test class? I added it to my post.

Comment: my firstRedirect() calls a secondRedirect(), which then calls the final function to send the POST request. Does that mean I only need to call firstRedirect()?

Comment: @TylerZika Yes, you'd only need to call the firstRedirect method to get code coverage. Just make sure you add some asserts to make sure you're getting the correct results back.